# How to specify decimal delimiter for Scanner.nextDouble()

Tags: java, double, delimiter

I have a fairly simple problem. I am getting real-number input like`6.03`, but that gives me errors. If I change it to `6,03`, it's ok. I, however, can't change the input I need to process, so how do I tell Java to use `.` as the delimiter instead of `,`?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double gX = sc.nextDouble(); // Getting errors
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code. There are various ways of performing this conversion, and we've no idea what you're using.

Comment: Code added. Didn't think it was important, but here goes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Scanner` can be provided with `Locale` to use, you need to specify `Locale` that uses `.` as decimal separator:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running into Locale issues.  You can use [java.text.NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) for parsing.

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
Number number = format.parse("6.03");
double d = number.doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Taken directly from the manual.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

**Locale-Sensitive Formatting**

The preceding example created a DecimalFormat object for the default Locale. If you want a DecimalFormat object for a nondefault Locale, you instantiate a NumberFormat and then cast it to DecimalFormat. Here's an example:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(loc);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
df.applyPattern(pattern);
String output = df.format(value);
System.out.println(pattern + " " + output + " " + 
                   loc.toString());
```

Running the previous code example results in the output that follows. The formatted number, which is in the second column, varies with Locale:

```
###,###.###      123,456.789     en_US
###,###.###      123.456,789     de_DE
###,###.###      123 456,789     fr_FR
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of code just to do that, considering that in Delphi one can just do `DecimalSeparator := '|';` and be done. Thanks though

Comment: @Magicmaster: And that would presumably be a global change, affecting global state? Not really a good idea...