# Formatting double Android

Tags: java, android

I want to turn e.g. *5999.635554 to 5 999,63* . I used `DecimalFormat` method below:

```
public static String decimalDoubleForm(double value){

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.00");
        String formatted_value = df.format(value).replaceAll("\\.", ",");

        return formatted_value;

}
```

However when i used it that is `Util.decimalDoubleForm(value);` on e.g. *-4000.4343* i get the following *-4,000,43*.

my desired result should be *-4000.4343* => *-4 000,43*.

Comment: Try using the string `# ###,###.00` in your DecimalFormat?

Comment: The following link might be useful :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081814/how-to-specify-decimal-delimiter

Good luck ^^

Comment: are you will to format price in german format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `-4,000.43` (the string from the `format()` call) to become `-4 000,43`, you can do *two* replacements.

The first is to replace all `,` characters with spaces, *then* replace all `.` characters with `,`.

```
String formatted_value = df.format(value)
    .replaceAll(","  , " ")
    .replaceAll("\\.", ",");
```

That gets problematic when you want to *swap* `,` and `.` <sup>(a)</sup> but you can still do that, albeit with a 3-step process:

```
comma  => X
period => comma
X      => period
```

(where `X` is any character that otherwise doesn't appear in the string, like, for example, `"X"`).

However, there may be a format string you can use for this already without needing string replacements. From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), it appears that the special characters are localised so there should be a way to create a `DecimalFormat` with a specific `DecimalFormatSymbol` based on the locale.

At least that's the case within Java proper. Whether Java Android can do the same thing, I'm not sure. They have been known to take a different tack on internationalisation before.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Darn those Europeans and their funny numeric formats :-)

Comment: @ paxdiablo said, "There may be a format string you can use for this already without needing string replacements." where can i find this functionality, any idea ?

Comment: @Dimitri, I''ve shown the Java classes that will do it a la `DecimalFormat (DecimalFormatSymbols (Locale))`. But I'm not sure if that's supported in Android. You'll have to validate that yourself, I'm afraid. If it's not available, the multi-`replaceAll()` solution should work, despite its ugliness.

Comment: @ paxdiablo:  thank you i get desired result with .replaceAll(","  , " ")
    .replaceAll("\\.", ",");