# File doesn't have values

Tags: java, arrays, file, input, while-loop

My invoer.txt file has double values. But Java gives a return as: There are no values.
How could I fix this? Because I think the code should work.

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class Lezen {
  private static int aantal = 0;
  private static double totaal = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("src/Opdracht_11_1/invoer.txt"));

    while (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        double cijfer = sc.nextDouble();

        aantal++;
        totaal = totaal + cijfer;

        System.out.println(cijfer);
    }

    System.out.println("Er staan " + aantal + " getallen in de file");
    System.out.println("Het gemiddelde is: " + (totaal / aantal));


    sc.close();
      }
    }
```

Content of txt file:

```
45.13
188.001
-17.3
12345
-7980.675
```

Output:

Er staan 0 getallen in de file

Het gemiddelde is: NaN

Comment: How is data stored in the file?

Comment: Please show the content of your file. What's the output of your program? (If you're going to give an English translation in the text of your question, it would be useful to change the code in a similar way :)

Comment: Does the text uses a decimal point `.` or do you not use any decimal point, or use a decimal comma instead?

Comment: If the data is in new line the code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this might be a locale issue.

- The Scanner.hasNextDouble and nextDouble methods are documented to use the locale-specific "LocalDecimalSeparator" character as the decimal "point".
- The OP's language appears to be Dutch.  (That's what Google translate thinks ...)
- The locale-specific "LocalDecimalSeparator" character in the "nl-NL" locale is "," ... according to this page: http://www.localeplanet.com/java/nl-NL/

However, the input file is using the "." character as the decimal point.

This could cause the numbers in the file to not be accepted by the scanner.

Try changing the "." decimal points to "," characters.

If this is the problem AND you need to read the file as given, then the solution is to change the locale that is in effect when you read the file:

- You can do this external to the application; e.g. by changing environment variables (on Unix / Linux).
- You can do this within the application by changing the default `Locale`; e.g. using `Locale.setDefault(...)`.
- You can do this just for a specific `Scanner`; e.g. using `Scanner.useLocale(...)`.  (See also: [How to specify decimal delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081814/how-to-specify-decimal-delimiter).)